# Include js, html and css files to an angular project

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a javascript project. I want to run those within an angular project.

Can I integrate js project to an angular project?

Can I get those js files to assets folder? If yes, where do we integrate those HTML and CSS files?

Please help me on this

Comment: I haven't worked with Angular but if you are using Visual Studio, right-click on the folder project and choose "Add Existing Item". Then find your files and add it.

Comment: i need it with an angular project

Answer (score 0):

```
app/
----- controllers/
---------- mainController.js
---------- otherController.js
----- directives/
---------- mainDirective.js
---------- otherDirective.js
----- services/
---------- userService.js
---------- itemService.js
----- js/
---------- bootstrap.js
---------- jquery.js
----- app.js
views/
----- mainView.html
----- otherView.html
----- index.html
```

Comment: How about css? Where to add the css files

Comment: https://blog.revillweb.com/angularjs-by-example-project-structure-and-modularity-ace27d0357ea get more help from here

Answer (score 0):

you can import the css or html file into the index.html file like so:

`import "~/filename.css"`

you can also include the css or javascript file, by including the pathtofile inside the angular.json file

`"style:"pathtocss",
"script":"pathtojs"`